# Test with Mockito for database delete method

Tags: jpa, mockito, dao

I want to test my delete method in PersonDao class.

```
public class PersonDao {
    private EntityManager em;
    Person person1 = new Person(111, "Klara", "Bamp", "qwerty123");

    public PersonDao() {
    }

    public PersonDao(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }
    public void delete(Person p) {
        em.remove(p);
    }
}
```

That's my test class:

```
public class UnitTests {
@Mock
EntityManager entityManagerMock;

@Before
public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void deletePersonTestWithMockito() {
    //ARRANGE
    PersonDao personDao = new PersonDao(entityManagerMock);
    when(entityManagerMock.find(Person.class, person1.getId())).thenReturn(person1);
    //ACT
    personDao.delete(person1);
    //ASSERT
    verify(entityManagerMock, times(1)).remove(person1);
    assertNull(entityManagerMock.find(Person.class, person1.getId()));
}
```

I realize, that personDao.delete(person1) does nothing, bcs I did not specify what entityManagerMock.remove should do. I tried to specify it as
`when(entityManagerMock.remove(person1)).thenCallRealMethod();`, but I received an error `Required type: T; Provided: void`

Comment: You can use Spy instead of Mock. https://javapointers.com/java/unit-test/difference-between-spy-and-mock-in-mockito/

Comment: okay, I fixed it like this, but I'm new to unit tests and I don't know if this test makes sense. Could you please tell me if it's ok? PersonDao personDao = new PersonDao(entityManagerSpy);
personDao.delete(person1);
verify(entityManagerSpy, times(1)).remove(person1);
assertNull(entityManagerSpy.find(Person.class, person1.getId())); I'm afraid that this test checks nothing - entityManagerSpy.find(Person.class, person1.getId())) always returns null

Comment: since it is unit test, the only goal of it is checking that expected methods are called. Since there is no real DB is used. So you shouldn't check `assertNull(entityManagerSpy.find(Person.class, person1.getId()));`. You should check only `remove` method invocation

Comment: thank you very much!